# How Can I Remove / Hide the Dates from Facebook Comments on my Wordpress Blog?

Tags: facebook, comments, date, facebook-comments

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I was able to successfully remove date stamps from my wordpress blog comments, but I'm also using a plugin that allows visitors to comment using their facebook accounts.

I can't seem to able to figure out how to hide or remove the dates from these facebook comments.

The facebook plugin uses a code that is placed in the header I believe. I think I can edit that if there is a way to remove or hide date stamps from comments.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the plugin is built using the Facebook JavaScript API, you'll want to navigate to the plugin folder: /wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN-NAME/

Look through each of the files, usually with most plugins your looking for a file with the same name as the plugin name: plugin-name.php.

There may be supporting JS files for it depending on how the plugin is built. You are looking for code that gets comments based on post_id (so you can try and do a search on each page for post_id). Once you find where the code is at you can find where the date is being pulled from and just get rid of it.

JavaScript API for comments: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.ApiClient.stream_getComments/

FYI: It would help if I knew what plugin you are talking about.